# Bootstrap collapsible panel to not collapse on another panel opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a collapsible panel using Bootstrap Collapse as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/3gYa3/) I would like to know if it is possible to keep one panel open while the other panel is opened and the panel closes only on the click of the arrow of it's own panel.

I have put the code for the css portion.

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
/* symbol for "opening" panels */
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
/* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the data-parent attribute on the anchor tags.

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<h2>Multiple Slides:</h2>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Group #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
          Group #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          Group #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```